# Design DFA accepting decimal strings divisible by 7

Tags: automata, finite-automata, dfa

I'm a student studying DFAs looking for a DFA that could find if a decimal number is divisible by 7.

today I've solved divisibility problem for numbers 2,3,4,5,6,8,9 but I can't solve this problem for number 7. I've searched the web but I couldn't find any answer helping me or being understandable for me.

so now I'm here looking for help. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic idea is that we will keep track of the current value, modulo seven, of the number we've seen so far. Each new digit takes the old number, multiplies by ten, and adds the new digit. Therefore, from the state corresponding to x (mod 7), adding digit d to the right means we go to the state corresponding to 10x + d (mod 7). This DFA has 70 states (the number of digits 0-9 times the number of remainders after division by seven 0-6).

```
q    s    q'
------------
q0   0    q0
q0   1    q1
q0   …    …
q0   6    q6

q1   0    q3
q1   1    q4
q1   …    …
q1   6    q2

…

q6   0    q4
q6   1    q5
q6   …    …
q6   6    q3
```

Consider the processing of the number 36736:

```
(q0) --3--> (q3) --6--> (q1) --7--> (q3) --3--> (q5) --6--> (q0)
0           0*10+3      3*10+6      1*10+7      3*10+3      5*10+6
            0+3         30+6        10+7        30+3        50+6
            3           36          17          33          56
            3           1           3           5           0
```

This number is divisible by seven because we end up in state q0, the state corresponding to zero modulo seven - meaning an even multiple of seven.

Comment: Wow! so your algorithm is a proof for "we can design a DFA for any number". thanks.

Comment: @Peymanmohsenikiasari Correct. In fact, we can make a DFA for this problem regardless of the number (seven as in this problem, but any number would work) and regardless of the number system base (decimal here, but the same principal works in any place-value system... just change 10 to your base)

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be helpful you can check this DFA by reminder(for ex. Binary 1001 = Decimal 9 and 9 mod 7 = 2 so our string 1001 should be end at q2.[Check Image for DFA Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2raxR.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).